# Change navbar bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap to build my website. I have a typical navbar with menu options, but I need to change the CSS to produce something like the image below (that will continuos work on mobile).

[image: expected result]

The image represents the expected result.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-default-light navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="index.php"><img src="assets/img/img.png" width="152px"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="index.php"></a>
                    <!-- menu options -->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS used code: the css of [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) class is the default used in Boostrap.

```
.navbar-default {
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #1f3741;
    padding: 25px 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
    -moz-transition: padding .3s;
    transition: padding .3s;
}
.navbar-default-light{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
   font-family : Lato,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,cursive;
    color: #1676a9;  
    margin-top:-10px;
}
 .navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.02);
    padding-top: 15px;
}    
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #1676a9;
    background-color: #1676a9;
}    
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}   
.navbar-default .nav li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Raleway", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.2;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.navbar-default-light .navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.navbar-default-light .nav li a {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}   
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you mean you always want your nav bar to look like the 2nd image you've posted here?

Comment: yes, I need to change my actual nav bar to look like the first and second image. second image is for mobile views.

Comment: @Jcbo You would use media queries in CSS to control how the navigation displays on different view port sizes. Please post your existing navigation CSS for us to review.

Comment: Check out the docs here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors you can change things using Bootstrap's classes and media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some ***overlapping*** style on bootstrap classes to design for *second image*.
I hope this below snipped will help you lot.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.navbar-default-light{
  border-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #1676a9;    
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.02);
}      
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 14px;
  height: 3px;
}   
.navbar-default-light .nav li{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar-default-light .nav li a {
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
}   
.navbar-default-light .navbar-toggle{
  display: block;
  right: -15px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  background: #999;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar-default-light .navbar-toggle:hover{background: #999; opacity: 0.75}
.navbar-default-light .navbar-toggle:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 10px;
  left: -46.5px;
  background: #1676a9;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  z-index: 0;
}
.navbar-right {
  float: none!important; 
  margin-right: 0px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.collapse.in, .collapsing{
  width: 100%!important;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.navbar-items{
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}
@media(max-width: 767.98px){
 .navbar-default-light .navbar-toggle {
    right: -30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-default-light navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header" style="position: relative; width: 100%;">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bscollapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse1 navbar-items" id="bscollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Menu #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu #14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Last</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
</nav>


<div style="min-height: 100vh; padding-top: 70px;">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
     Last Line...
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```